# JPA what's the best way to get an summary object?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have an default spring web MVC application, I'm using JPA and some times I need to create some kind of Summary view page, for example: I have three objects (in my case I have many) House, Car and Person, in this example the House has Cars and Persons, so in my page view I need to do something like

```
House 1: 5 Cars, 6 Persons
House 2: 3 Cars, 3 Persons
House 3: 6 Cars, 2 Persons etc...
```

I was thinking about using native queries, because I'm very good with SQL queries so there is no problem with that, but JPA does not have something that return like an MAP of Strings, and I don't know anything about JPA performance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the requirement is already addressed in the [official JPA documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_04/ejb3_langref.html).

Comment: So, may we don't have to ask about what are already in the official documentation, but I think almost everything it's documented in its documentation, the problem is: I search It in stackoverflow (because I have some kind of paranoia, I think that everything is here) I didn't find a similar question or answer, so I asked. I did bad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JPA query

```
SELECT
  h
  , COUNT(c)
  , COUNT(p)
FROM
  House h
LEFT JOIN
  h.cars c
LEFT JOIN
  h.persons p
GROUP BY
  h
```

can be executed as `entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList()` to get a `List<Object[]>`.

Each element of the `List` will be an array of three values (corresponding to the three values in the `SELECT` clause). The first value will be of type `House` (due to `SELECT h`), whereas the second and third will be of the type `Long`.

Query performance will not be drastically different from running a native query from the same application as the translation from JPQL to SQL is quite quick.